# Attenuation estimation of the solution of the two-dimensional wave equation Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, estimation, wave-equation, cauchy-problem

This is the equation given,
$$\begin{array}{l}
u_{tt}=a^{2}\left(u_{x x}+u_{y y}\right), \\
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\left.u\right|_{t=0}=\varphi(x, y), \\
\left.u_{t}\right|_{t=0}=\psi(x, y) .
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}$$
Its solution $u(x,y,t)$ can be given by Poisson's formula,

$$
\begin{align*}
  u(x,y,t) = {} 
    & \frac{1}{2\pi a}\biggl[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
      \iint_{\Sigma_{at}^M}
      \frac{\varphi(\xi,\eta)d\xi d\eta}{\sqrt{a^2t^2-(\xi-x)^2-(\eta-y)^2}} \\
    & + \iint_{\Sigma_{at}^M}\frac{\psi(\xi,\eta)d\xi d\eta}
      {\sqrt{a^2t^2-(\xi-x)^2-(\eta-y)^2}}\biggr].
\end{align*}
$$

If the initial data $\varphi$ and $\psi$ has compact support  (for any fixed point M = ($x_0$, $y_0$) $∈$ $\mathbb{R}
^2$
, there exists some $ρ > 0$ such that both
$φ$ and $ψ$ vanish outside $Σ^M
_ρ$ and are bounded in $Σ^M
_ρ$).

For any given $(x_0,y_0)$, how to prove

$$u(x_0,y_0,t)=O(t^{-\frac{1}{2}}),t\to\infty.$$

The estimation I can get is $O(t^{-1}),$

\begin{align*}
    u(x_0,y_0,t) = {} 
    & \frac{1}{2\pi a}\biggl[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
      \iint_{\Sigma_{at}^M}
      \frac{\varphi(\xi,\eta)d\xi d\eta}{\sqrt{a^2t^2-(\xi-x_0)^2-(\eta-y_0)^2}} \\
    & + \iint_{\Sigma_{at}^M}\frac{\psi(\xi,\eta)d\xi d\eta}
      {\sqrt{a^2t^2-(\xi-x_0)^2-(\eta-y_0)^2}}\biggr] \\
={} & \frac{1}{2\pi a}\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^{at}\int_0^{2\pi}
      \frac{\varphi(x_0+r\cos\theta,y_0+r\sin\theta)}{\sqrt{a^2t^2-r^2}}r d\theta d r \\
    & +\int_0^{at}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\psi(x_0+r\cos\theta,y_0+r\sin\theta)}
      {\sqrt{a^2t^2-r^2}}rd\theta d r\bigg] \\
={} & \frac{1}{2\pi a}\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
      \int_0^{\rho}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\varphi(x_0+r\cos\theta,y_0+r\sin\theta)}
      {\sqrt{a^2t^2-r^2}}rd\theta d r \\
    & + \int_0^{\rho}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\psi(x_0+r\cos\theta,y_0+r\sin\theta)}{\sqrt{a^2t^2-r^2}}rd\theta d r\bigg] \\
={} & \frac{1}{2\pi a}\bigg[\int_0^{\rho}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
      \frac{\varphi(x_0+r\cos\theta,y_0+r\sin\theta)}{\sqrt{a^2t^2-r^2}}rd\theta d r \\
    & + \int_0^{\rho}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\psi(x_0+r\cos\theta,y_0+r\sin\theta)}
      {\sqrt{a^2t^2-r^2}}rd\theta d r\bigg].
  \end{align*}
Thus when $t\to +\infty$,
\begin{split}
  |u(x_0,y_0,t)|&\leq \frac{1}{2\pi a}\left[2\pi C\int_0^{\rho}-a^2t(a^2t^2-r^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}r d r+2\pi C\int_0^{\rho}\frac{r}{\sqrt{a^2t^2-r^2}}dr\right]\\
  &=\frac{1}{2\pi a}\left[2\pi C\left(a-\frac{a^2t}{\sqrt{a^2t^2-\rho^2}}\right)+2\pi C(at-\sqrt{a^2t^2-\rho^2})\right] \\
& = O(t^{-1}).
  \end{split}

Comment: As $t \to \infty, 1/t \ll 1/\sqrt{t},$ so the $O(1/t)$ bound already implies an $O(1/\sqrt{t})$ bound.